# How can you or How could you?

Tags: modal-verbs

If you see somone acting rude now, would a native speaker say:

> "How can you be so rude?"

or:

> "How could you be so rude"?

Answer (score 1):

As a native English speaker, I would say that either one equally conveys the same meaning: offense and possible disgust at their inappropriate behavior.

Comment: "How could you have poisoned John? He was your brother." Do you think "How could you poison John?" conveys the same meaning?